apex-mdapi calls starts failing with INVALID_SESSION_ID when it was working a few hours ago
Use case:

Apex code makes use of the Apex MDAPI wrapper apex-mdapi
Context is schedule-triggered flow invocable and hence UserInfo.getSessionId() is not available or not usable hence ..

Metadata API callout done with Named/External Credentials, OAuth client credentials flow



Worked great yesterday, no code or config changes and it fails today with error
WebService returned a SOAP Fault: INVALID_SESSION_ID: 
Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session. 
Session not found, missing session hash pfxpYBsZxBovuh9bnP2/D5REEjJ7BQN4pkyVXD61m0o=

This error usually occurs after a session expires or a user logs out. 
Decoder: DataInDbSessionKeyDecoder faultcode=sf:INVALID_SESSION_ID faultactor=

Status code = 500

I thought that using Named Credentials with an Auth Provider that includes OAuth scopes refresh_token, full, and offline_access would automatically handle session expiry
Why is the session expiring?

A hat tip goes to the folks at Groundswell Cloud Solutions who wrote a blog post on using Named Credentials and the apex-mdapi. Given that that post might be taken down or re-hosted, I thought I'd preserve its essence here:

But wait – didn’t we give our connected apps the offline_access and refresh_token scopes? Shouldn’t Named Credentials automatically refresh our access_token when it expires? What’s going on?
After discussions with Salesforce Support (and subsequently, product management), it turns out that this was an unexpected “bug” that is somewhat difficult to fix, so they have published this article for future reference.
The root cause is that, for historical reasons, the Metadata API is returning an HTTP 500 when the session expires, not a 401, so the Named Credentials infrastructure doesn’t know to try to do a token refresh; it can’t differentiate between a “500 because the session has expired”, and a “500 because something genuinely went wrong”.

So, using the SFDC article guidance about making a REST call to reestablish the session before I do any SOAP calls to the Metadata API, I ended up with this:
void doWork() {
  reestablishSession();
  MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
  service.endpoint_x = 'callout:ApexMDApi' + '/services/Soap/m/42.0';
  service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
  service.SessionHeader.sessionId = '{!$Credential.OAuthToken}';
  .. marshal args to MDAPI and call appropriate service.xxxMethod
}

void reestablishSession() {
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('callout:ApexMDApi/services/data/v62.0/limits/');
    req.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(req);
    if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() != 200) {
        throw new MyOAuthException('Unable to make REST call to /limits to reestablish OAuth session for SOAP MDAPI calls: ' +
            httpResponse.getStatusCode() + ' ' + httpResponse.getStatus());
    }
}
    

Crude and burns a callout but that's OK in my app.  A cleverer design would catch the INVALID_SESSION_ID error on the SOAP call, then retry after calling reestablishSession()
Note that with Named Credentials External Credentials you can specify additional status codes that indicate refresh is required. However, these have to be valid 4xx status codes. 500 does not work so this config option is not available.

